# Java Agent Framework the best way to implement mandatory message delivering

Tags: java, design-patterns, protocols, agents-jade

I`m using JADE agents in my architecture. They are expected to be used in complicated long dialog between each other. I need to implement a mandatory delivering for this messages. Something like send message the same or change some parameter if it wasn`t successfully delivered to the receiver agent. Is this ability already implemented in JADE or FIPA? What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you really should read some JADE documentation, you could find a good and objective reference about that in the chapter 5 of: [JADE Tutorial for beginners](http://jade.tilab.com/doc/tutorials/JADEProgramming-Tutorial-for-beginners.pdf)